# ArrayList of int[] in a recursive method

Tags: java, loops, recursion, arraylist

I have a project to do for school in which i have to use a recursive method that will calculate all the switching possibilities between some numbers.
I.E : [1,2] => 1,2 and 2,1.

So i've used this method and it seemed to be working properly when i just print the solutions on the console, but when i want to stock the tabs in an ArrayList (i need to use them later) it will always add the same order. In my exemple it would have added 1,2 and 1,2 instead of 1,2 and 2,1.

Here's my code :

```
public  static void permute(int start, int[] input, ArrayList <int[]> al) { 
    //This method is recursive, it will open multiple instances of the input tab by calling itself and modify them, then stock tab in ArrayList when the operations are done for this tab.
    //ArrayList must be empty.

    //Printing tab if iterations for that specific tab are done
    if (start == input.length) {
        al.add(input);
        ////////////////////////////////
        // For printing tabs in console.
        // for(int x: input){
        // System.out.print(x);
        // }
        // System.out.println("");
        ////////////////////////////////
    //End the specific tab loop when it's printed 

    return;
    }
    for (int i = start; i < input.length; i++) {
        // Changing numbers
        int temp = input[i];
        input[i] = input[start];
        input[start] = temp;

        //////////////////////////////////////////////////
        // Tests to see algorithm steps
        //
        // System.out.print("temp : " + temp + " ... ");
        // System.out.print("i : "+i + " ... ");
        // System.out.print("start : " + start);
        // System.out.println("");
        // System.out.print("---");
        // for(int x: input){
        //  System.out.print(x);
        // }
        // System.out.println("");
        //////////////////////////////////////////////////

        //Changing numbers
        permute(start + 1, input, al);

       // Changing numbers
        int temp2 = input[i];
        input[i] = input[start];
        input[start] = temp2;

}
```

}

I use start = 0, input = {1,2,3} and the ArrayList is empty before the method starts.

Hope you can help, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are adding a reference to an array into your ArrayList, reference that you then keep changing in your algorithm.

By the end of it, you will have perm(N) copies of the same array.

All you have to do is to add a **deep-copy** of the array into the ArrayList, like this:

```
al.add(Arrays.copyOf(input, input.length));
```

instead of

```
al.add(input);
```

Printing the resulting ArrayList will then produce the following output:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 3, 2]
[2, 1, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
[3, 2, 1]
[3, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked !
But can I ask you the difference between my line and the deep-copy ? I mean when should I use the deep-copy over the input reference?

Comment: You want to use deep-copy anytime you want to get a real new copy of the object, rather than just a copy of the current reference to the Object. the latter, will not safeguard you against other code modifying the underlying object through the reference they hold, exactly what was tripping you here. To understand why this is necessary, google for "is java pass by reference or value?"